# perl queue files opening with threads

Tags: multithreading, perl

I have simple sites checker with multithreading.
I trying open in loop txt files in this dir

```
my @files = glob( '*.txt' );

foreach my $file(@files){

   @sites=load_file($file);
   $total_count = scalar(@sites);

   for my $t (1..$threads) {
     push @threads, threads->create(\&check, $t);#check- main subroutine
     threads->create(\&stat)->join() if $t == $threads;#stat - realtime statistics(good/bads) sites
   }

   foreach my $t (@threads) {
     $t->join();
   }
}
```

But it work only for first file and program terminated.
Can anyone help?
Thanks.

Comment: did you `use strict; use warnings`? Where is `@threads` declared? Why isn't it declared *inside* the outer loop? Also, I can't see any interaction between the threads and the `@sites`. Do you know about [`Thread::Queue`](https://metacpan.org/module/Thread::Queue)?

Comment: Yes. Because it is not relevant to the issue. Subroutine check uses @sites.

Comment: If you don't know why your program isn't working then you can't say what is relevant to the issue. Please post your entire code. I can see no declarations at all in this fragment, and I suspect a mishandling of `@sites`, `$threads` or `@threads` elsewhere.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are doing threading with Perl, there are a few things to avoid:

- excessive forking / creation of new processes
- shared state, or sharing anything at all that isn't immutable or synchronized!

Your code uses a hardwired limit of `$threads`. But you pass and index to a global (*shudder*) array (forgetting the first index), so some sites may go unchecked. Also, you create a new set of threads for every set of sites, which seems wasteful.

Now lets assume we have a Thread::Queue. Then  we start by creating a few threads:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

use strict; use warnings; use threads; use Thread::Queue;
use constant THREADS => 5; # or whatever

my $queue = Thread::Queue->new();

my @threads = map threads->new(\&check, $queue),  1 .. THREADS;
```

Our `check` subroutine takes a queue as argument, from which it will get the sites:

```
sub check {
  my $q = shift;
  while (defined(my $site = $q->dequeue)) {
    ...; # check the site.
  }
}
```

Then (after starting the threads), we fill the queue with sites:

```
for my $file (@files) {
   my @sites = load_file($file);
   $queue->enqueue( @sites ); # keep queue operations to minimum
   # maybe wait until there are less that n sites in the queue
}
```

After the files are finished, we enqueue `undef` values; this causes the threads to terminate:

```
$queue->enqueue( (undef) x THREADS );
$_->join for @threads;
```

Answer (score 2):

"Site checker" is certainly an I/O bound problem, while threads/forks are better suited to solve CPU bound problems. Parallel requests over network can be single-process if you use asynchronous approach. Here's one really simple checker using [YADA](https://metacpan.org/module/YADA) module from CPAN, which uses 4 parallel connections by default:

```
#!/usr/bin/env perl
use common::sense;

use YADA;

YADA->new->append(
    [qw[
        http://www.cpan.org/modules/by-category/02_Language_Extensions/
        http://www.cpan.org/modules/by-category/02_Perl_Core_Modules/
        http://www.cpan.org/modules/by-category/03_Development_Support/
        http://www.cpan.org/modules/by-category/27_Pragma/
        http://www.cpan.org/modules/by-category/28_Perl6/
        http://www.cpan.org/modules/by-category/99_Not_In_Modulelist/
    ]] => sub {
        say $_[0]->final_url;
        say ${$_[0]->header};
    },
)->wait;
```